How to scale socketcluster across multiple droplets?
This is my first question ever, I hope it's written in a manner that can be understood. So to get straight to the point, we currently have more users our application, and many realtime socket is being used, and the API is starting to get pretty slow. Looking for a way to have socketcluster work with Nodejs cluster and scale it horizontaly across multiple Digital Ocean droplets to improve performance. Using PM2 for process manager
I started by implementing clustering, it worked but socket cluster stopped working for some reason.
